# an abstract base class(abc) giving error __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python

I am getting an error when instantiating a class like:

```
GoogleCrawler('foods')
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
Process terminated with an exit code of 1
```

I am using an abstraction class (abc) which might be creating the problem. 
I call the class like:

```
from crawler.GoogleCrawler import GoogleCrawler

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #w = GoogleCrawler(search_key='PKK')
    GoogleCrawler('foods')
```

Here is the code:

BaseCrawler.py

```
class BaseCrawler(ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, search_key='', **kwargs):

        if type(search_key) == str:
            if search_key == '':
                search_key = 'Kabe'
            self.g_search_key_list = [search_key]


        code continues ...
```

GoogleCrawler.py contains

```
from BaseCrawler import BaseCrawler

class GoogleCrawler(BaseCrawler):

    def __init__(self, search_key='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(search_key, **kwargs)

        # google search specific url parameters
        self.search_url_prefix = kwargs.get('search_url_prefix', 'https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=')
        self.search_url_postfix = kwargs.get('search_url_postfix','&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=0eZEVbj3IJG5uATalICQAQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=939&bih=591')

        # show more options
        # options : 'id','class'
        self.show_more_find_type = kwargs.get('show_more_find_type', 'id')
        self.show_more_find_value = kwargs.get('show_more_find_value', 'smb')


       code continues ...
```

Comment: `class BaseCrawler(ABCMeta):` is inheriting from `ABCMeta`, rather than using it as a metaclass.

Comment: When using class BaseCrawler(metaclass=ABCMeta): its says invalid syntax, any recommendations?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? And why exactly are you trying to use an abstract base class in the first place?

Comment: Using Python version 2.7 there is no such strict requirement just using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what Daniel Roseman suggested (adding a `__metaclass__ = ABCMeta` to `BaseCrawler`), you also need to add arguments to the call to `super()` in `GoogleCrawler`, because in Python 2 it always requires at least one argument (two were needed in this case).

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class BaseCrawler(object):  # CHANGED BASE CLASS
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta    # ADDED

    def __init__(self, search_key='', **kwargs):
        if type(search_key) == str:
            if search_key == '':
                search_key = 'Kabe'
            self.g_search_key_list = [search_key]

class GoogleCrawler(BaseCrawler):
    def __init__(self, search_key='', **kwargs):
        # FOLLOWING LINE CHANGED TO SUPPLY NEEDED ARGS TO super()
        super(GoogleCrawler, self).__init__(search_key, **kwargs)

        # google search specific url parameters
        self.search_url_prefix = kwargs.get('search_url_prefix', 'https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=')
        self.search_url_postfix = kwargs.get('search_url_postfix','&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=0eZEVbj3IJG5uATalICQAQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=939&bih=591')

        # show more options
        # options : 'id','class'
        self.show_more_find_type = kwargs.get('show_more_find_type', 'id')
        self.show_more_find_value = kwargs.get('show_more_find_value', 'smb')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GoogleCrawler('foods')
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for clarifying about the super(). It was helpful.

Answer (score 6):

With Python 2.x you need to specify the metaclass as a special attribute of the class.

```
class BaseCrawler(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
```